# What is the function of a hidden or delayed member in a mongo replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I was reading the docs of [Delayed Member](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/replica-set-delayed-member/) and [Hidden member](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) but i didnt understand or imagine which could be a use case where you could use it or need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden members are useful for running really heavy queries that might otherwise impact other operations.  Since the hidden node will never be discovered, you can only connect to it directly.  This is typically used for analytics, such as end-of-month processing where the queries run are expected to take minutes or hours, and the load of running these heavy queries would cause unacceptable latency for day-to-day operations that would normally run on a secondary.

Delayed members are useful for having a view of the data a few minutes/hours/days ago.  This can be useful if you need to have the ability to rollback to an earlier time, or as a hot backup to protect against mistakes that might be made.  i.e. a developer accidentally dropped the entire database? No problem! Just pull a copy from the delayed node.

Comment: What an answer! Thank you so much @Joe